# Principle Component Analysis for Feature extraction from Voltage and Current Signals

Tags: time-series, pca, feature-selection

I am doing research work on fault classification in power transmission lines. I generated fault datasets in MATLAB/Simulink and collected it in matrix format with 6 various i.e. 6 variables in 6 columns of matrix.

I have performed Principle Component Analysis to reduce dimensions to  one-dimension for feature extraction to be applied to the machine learning classifiers.

I am confused about it whether it will provide the correct features (maximum features in the first principle component)? Can anyone explain it as first PC contain almost 69% features whereas first two PCs show 100% features. May I use it as a sequence or time series with a label in this format or anything else?

Comment: Please, would you mind explaining to those who are not electrical engineers where time kicks in your matrix dataset (is it one of your 5 or 6 regressors/features)?

Comment: There is total 6 variables in it for a specific type of fault i.e. 3 currents and 3 voltages for a 3-phase transmission line. The time is not included as a separate variable in any column but corresponds to the rows of the matrix (each column is a timeseries, samples at particular frequency).  It generates six principal components (PC1-PC6) as there are six variables in this matrix and PC1 contains most of the information in it. My question was whether I can use PC1 as sequence instead of matrix for this particular type of fault because I have confusion its use in this way.

Comment: You mentioned "fault". What is faulting? A device, which is attached to one of the three phases?

Comment: In that case, one phase (its current and voltage) explains everything...

Comment: In normal transmission line, V,I values remain within limits. These deviate from normal value when abnormal condition occurs, called a fault (generally speaking short circuit faults). Fault may occur in transmission lines due to natural causes as well as living beings. @Alex please read this article for general understanding and more information. https://www.google.com/search?q=transmission+line+fault&rlz=1C1CHBF_en__1022__1022&oq=transmiion+line+fault&aqs=chrome.2.69i57j0i13i512l9.9314j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Answer (score 0):

The answer is yes. One can use sequence or timeseries generated by PCA for fault classification in transmission lines. Here is the story. I generated a fault sample in Simulink/MATLAB, saved data to workspace and exported to Microsoft Excel (6 columns matrix). The length of any column is the fault duration which may be added a separate column in the matrix but I did not. Then standardized, scaled data and PCA. PC1-PC6 were six principle components of the original matrix. Plotted the first PC1 which had waveform like the original one. All features were shown by the first two PCs.